# Fix canonicalization of News section for Codeigniter site

Tags: codeigniter, seo, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Google is indexing my news articles as:

https://www.site.com/news/id5-

and:

https://www.site.com/news/id5-title-of-article

In fact, it indexes both, but omits the full URL version in results. Both URLs resolve to the same address, but I want to force id#-title-of-article each time to fix this canonicalization issue.

The site is written using Codeignigter framework.

My routes file at system/application/config/routes.php contains:

```
$route['news/id(\d+)-(.*)'] = "news/view/$1";
```

Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On your header, let Google know what the common URL should be.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.site.com/news/id5-title-of-article" />
```

Make sure that this is available regardless of which page is loaded. It will take some time to re-index, but Google will only show this link on its search once indexed.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Is there no other option? I ask because when I have have 700 news articles, it will be impossible/inefficient to add this code to all pages of my site?

Comment: Based on the question (because it involves an ID) I thought your site is dynamically generated. Regardless of the number of the articles, it would be a single location (one line of code, perhaps) that you would need to update to generate this canonical tag.

Comment: Using your advice, I thought adding something similar to the following bit of code would allow me to specify the canonical of pages within NEWS.  


<?php
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($currentpage=="news/") {
<link rel="canonical" href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] ?><?php echo parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH); ?>" />
}
?>
 
The problem is that I don't know how to go about specifying that ONLY IF $currentpage is */news/id#-title, return <link rel="canonical"...  
I'm a noob and I appreciate your help